# How can I update mobile number in firebase authentication using the updateProfie Method?

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

I am collecting name, email, phone and password when a user sign up. In the useFirebase hook, I am updating the displayName using updateProfile method of firebase.

This function is used for creating user.

```
const userCreate = (name, email, password, phone, history) => {
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        .then((userCredential) => {
            //User Create after registration
            const newUser = { email, displayName: name, phoneNumber:phone };
           const uid = auth.currentUser.uid
            verifyEmail();
            updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {
                displayName: name, 
                phoneNumber:phone,
            })
                .then(() => {
                    console.log()
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                });
            history.replace('/');
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
}
```

After signup the displayName is updated. But I am not getting the phone number. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation on [updating a user's profile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#update_a_users_profile):

> You can update a user's basic profile information—the user's **display name and profile photo URL**—with the `updateProfile` method.

So there's no way to update the user's phone number with this function. The reason for this is that the phone number is part of a user's sign-in credentials, so needs to be updated through a dedicated method (similar to their password and email).

To update a user's phone number, call the `updatePhoneNumber` function as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#updatephonenumber):

```
// 'recaptcha-container' is the ID of an element in the DOM.
const applicationVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container');
const provider = new PhoneAuthProvider(auth);
const verificationId = await provider.verifyPhoneNumber('+16505550101', applicationVerifier);
// Obtain the verificationCode from the user.
const phoneCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId, verificationCode);
await updatePhoneNumber(user, phoneCredential);
```